# Need comma to separate SamAccountName from groups

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this script to extract users starting with the letter "m" and the groups they are members of. The result of the script is OK but I need the `SamAccountName` and the groups to be on the same line and to be separated by a comma so I can arrange it better in an Excel file. Any suggestions?

```
Import-Module activedirectory

$file=".\atos_user_m.csv"

foreach ($suser in (Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -like "m*"})) {
    $user = $suser.SamAccountName
    echo "`r`n"$user"`r`n" | Out-File $file -Append
    foreach ($group in (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user)) {
        $group.SamAccountName | Out-File $file -Append
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all groups for a given user in the same line as the username you could do something like this:

```
foreach ($suser in (Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -like "m*"})) {
    $user = $suser.SamAccountName
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user |
              Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName
    '{0},{1}' -f $user, ($groups -join ',') | Out-File $file -Append
}
```

or like this (using a pipeline):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -like "m*"} | ForEach-Object {
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.SamAccountName |
              Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName
    '{0},{1}' -f $_.SamAccountName, ($groups -join ',')
} | Out-File $file
```

Comment: I tried the first one and is exactly what i needed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add $user before the group.

```
import-module activedirectory
$file=".\atos_user_m.csv"

foreach ($suser in (get-aduser -filter {samaccountname -like "m*"})) {
    $user = $suser.samaccountName
    foreach ($group in (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user)) {
        $user + ',' + $group.SamAccountName  | out-file -filepath $file -append
    }
}
```